# Sankey Diagram in R & plotly: unnexpected connections

Tags: r, plotly, sankey-diagram

I am trying to build Sankey plot with three layers in R using plotly package (plotly_4.10.2). Although connections from source to target seems reasonable from "links" data, plot itself displays connections incorrectly.

For example, "example.data" -> Gene3-Treatment-**Catogory2** is displayed as Gene3-Treatment-**Category1**, Connections for Gene8 is wrong as well. Should I do any rearrangement of labels before plotting?

Screenshot of the plot

[image]

```
library(plotly)

# this is an example data

example.data <- data.frame(
  genes = c("Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene3", "Gene4", "Gene5", "Gene6", "Gene7", "Gene8", "Gene9"),
  conditions = c("Control", "Control", "Treatment", "Treatment", "Treatment", "Treatment", "Treatment", "Treatment", "Treatment"),
  category = c("Category1", "Category1", "Category2", "Category2", "Category2", "Category2", "Category2", "Category1", "Category2")
)

nodes <- data.frame(name = unique(c(as.character(example.data$genes),
                                    as.character(example.data$conditions),
                                    as.character(example.data$category))))

links <- data.frame(source = match(example.data$genes, nodes$name) - 1,
                    target = match(example.data$conditions, nodes$name) - 1,
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

links <- rbind(links,
               data.frame(source = match(example.data$conditions, nodes$name) - 1,
                          target = match(example.data$category, nodes$name) - 1,
                          stringsAsFactors = FALSE))


plotly::plot_ly(
  type = "sankey",
  domain = list(x =  c(0,1),
                y =  c(0,1)),
  orientation = "h",
  customdata = nodes$name,
  node = list(
    label = nodes$name,
    pad = 15,
    thickness = 15,
    line = list(color = "black",
                width = 0.5)),
  link = list(source = links$source,
              target = links$target,
              value =   rep(1, nrow(links))
  ))
```

Comment: There is no relationship between genes and category. x number of genes are in treatment. And one of those treatments is in category1. This doesn't mean Gene3 is in category1.

Comment: Maybe try to plot in order: condition -> genes -> category

Comment: @zx8754 I tried  condition -> genes -> category and at least in this example, visually, connections align with the example data

Comment: The question is, do you want to split genes into category, or do you want to split conditions into category.

Comment: @zx8754 For me I interpet it like (again this is just toy data): Gene1 which originates from Control belongs to Category1. Btw each gene will belong to only one specific category and one specific condition. Also there is no "natural" connection between condition and category, connections here are meant to be continuation of connections coming from Genes. That said, what you suggest condition -> genes -> category is possibly a better fit, since genes are the ones that are truly connected to both condition and category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try to plot in this order: `condition -> genes -> category`:

```
nodes <- unique(unlist(example.data))

links <- list(
  source = c(match(example.data$conditions, nodes) - 1, 
             match(example.data$genes, nodes) - 1),
  target = c(match(example.data$genes, nodes) - 1,
             match(example.data$category, nodes) - 1),
  value = rep(1, nrow(example.data) * 2))

plot_ly(type = "sankey",
        node = list(label = nodes),
        link = links)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The connections are actually correct, the Sankey diagram display the flows between State 1 (source node) `genes` and State 2 (target node) `conditions` and then, separately, the flows between State 2 `conditions` and State 3 `category`.

It makes more sense if you hover over the flows, you will see that, for example, one value from `Treatment` went to `Category1`. However, just because the flow seems linked to `Gene3` does not necessarily mean that it is:

[image]

Comment: I see, thanks. Despite this, visually it is misleading